# Try connect to AD via Ldap

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I want to implement a function which connects to AD via Ldap.

My code:

```
public bool TryConnect(string server, string userName, string password)
{
    try
    {
        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(@"test\administrator123", @"P2ssw0rd");
        var ldapidentifier = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("Test");

        using (var ldapconn = new LdapConnection(ldapidentifier, credentials))
        {
            ldapconn.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
            var request = new SearchRequest("dc=test, dc=local", "(objectClass=user)", System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Subtree, null);
            var response = (SearchResponse)ldapconn.SendRequest(request);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This is working, but I don't like it !

Is there some cleaner way how to test connection without try/catch and without some dummy search request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of performing a search, you could call the [Bind()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ts65cab1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to test basic connectivity like so:

```
ldapconn.Bind();
```

However I don't know a way to test this without try/catch.